# Write grammar for language $L=\bigl\{ba^{2^n}b \mid n\ge 1\bigr\}$

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, formal-grammar

Write grammar for language $L=\{ba^{2^n}b | n\ge 1\}$. It can be grammar of any type without any restriction on rules look.
My best attempt is:
\begin{aligned}
S &\to RLM \\
M &\to AM | A \\
LA &\to aa \\
aA &\to Aaa \\
RA &\to \varepsilon
\end{aligned}
But I've found example with deadlock $S\to RLM\to RLAAA\to RaaAA \to RaAaaA \to RAaaaaA \to aaaaA$
So I'm stuck

Comment: Exactly what can be the rules? I guess, something like ^$wA\to ww$ is not allowed, where $w$ is general/varying, i.e. does not denote a specific word, and ^ denotes the beginning.

Comment: Rules doesn't have any restrictions on their left and right parts, but you have to use non-terminal and symbols a,b in any combinations

Comment: And, is it important to reach a 'leaf' of only non-terminals for every possible deduction branch? Can't we just say, that this branch doesn't produce any word for the language?

Comment: Yes, it's important. Grammar have to generate only words from language

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar, it seems there's no such explicit requirement in the definition of grammar. Also, "the language of G, denoted as L(G), is defined as all those sentences that can be derived in a finite number of steps from the start symbol S" -- this allows having deadlock deductions, those simply lead to nowhere.

Comment: Ah, this might be what you're looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566382/context-sensitive-type-1-grammar-for-a-power-of-two-number-of-as

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/91614/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2771255/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplified version of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566382/context-sensitive-type-1-grammar-for-a-power-of-two-number-of-as), relying on the exact same idea for the language $\{a^{2^n}\mid n\ge1\}$ is
$$\begin{align} S&\to BXAE\\ XA&\to AAX\\ XE&\to YE\,|\,F\\ AY&\to YA \\
BY&\to BX\\ AF&\to FA\\ BF&\to \varepsilon\\ A&\to a\end{align}$$